# JaVers debug logs

Tags: javers

Is there a way to enable debug logs for JaVers so I get more details than this?

`JaversException MANAGED_CLASS_MAPPING_ERROR: given javaClass 'class java.lang.Long' is mapped to ValueType, expected ManagedType`

The field name would be great to be able to figure out what needs to be mapped differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that's the malformed `byInstance` query. Try the latest version (3.6.2) with improved exception logging.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using 2.9.2, last one that runs on Java7 though :). Is there a way to get better logging for that?

Comment: I've been doing that and even added some error catching that gives me at least the class that failed. But that's not enough, as the error can be anywhere on the object graph starting from that class. E.g. I get  `JaversException PROPERTY_ACCESS_ERROR: error getting value from property 'Method ClassRepository getGenericInfo; //declared in: Class' on target object of type 'Class', cause: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null` on pretty much anything now and have no idea where to look.

Comment: Try to isolate the problem to the failing test case which you can push to github